# Sorting an array by reference

Tags: c++

I made a simple routine to sort an array witch accepts as a parameter an array of ints the problem is that when i compare the values array[i] shows the correct value in the debugger but array[i + 1] shows a bogus value ... i guess is a pointer issue but i can't figure it out what i am doing wrong.

Here is the code :

```
typedef int vector[10];

void task1(vector * param)
{
    bool ordered = false;
    while (!(ordered))
    {
        int tmp = 0;
        ordered = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9 ; i++)
        {
            if (*param[i] > *param[i+1])
            {
                tmp = *param[i];
                *param[i] = *param[i + 1];
                *param[i + 1] = tmp;
                ordered = false;
            }
        }
    }

}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    vector tavi = {10,88,77,192,7,27,82,1,882,13};

    task1(&tavi);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i ++)
        printf("%d ",tavi[i]);

    _getch();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you be interested in `std::array<int, 10>` and `std::sort`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The subscript-operator (`[]`) has a higher precedence than the derefence-operator (`*`), so `*param[i]` is actually `*(param[i])`. This means, you first go to the i-th element of `param`, and then dereference it - that is not what you want (`param` is not a pointer into an array). You want to dereference `param` and *then* go to the i-th element - this would be `(*param)[i]`.

Comment: I tryed *param[i] = *(param)[i + 1]; still the same result :(

Comment: @opc0de no, the star goes inside the parens: `(*param)[i + 1];`. Outside the parens it's the same as it was before.

Comment: Try `(*param)[i] = (*param)[i+1];`. The position of the `*` and brackets are important.

Comment: Read carefully - you need `(*param)[i] = (*param)[i+1]` - dereference inside the parentheses.

Comment: Sorry , it's very confusing to me writting c++ from delphi. Thanks very much it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: Why would you write the sorting yourself (not to mention that bubblesort is not exactly fast).
So why not simply use

```
std::sort(tavi, tavi + 10, std::less<int>());
```

Of course if you have C++11 or boost its also a good idea to forget about c style arrays and use `std::array` or `boost::array` instead:

```
std::array<int, 10> tavi = {10,88,77,192,7,27,82,1,882,13};

std::sort(tavi.begin(), tavi.end(), std::less<int>());
for (int i = 0 ; i < tavi.size(); i ++)
    std::cout<<tavi[i]<<" ";
```

If however you really want to do it like that, `*param[i]` is the same as `*(param[i])`, while you want to use `(*param)[i]`.

Comment: Thanks for your help but i am trying to perfect my c++ knowledge that is already limited i tried writting *param[i] = *(param)[i + 1]; still the same result ...

Comment: @opc0de : That's because you **still** have the parentheses in the wrong place.

Comment: @opc0de: Its not *(param)[i+1], but (*param)[i+1] which you should try (subtle difference in the position of *). If your comment about perfecting your c++ knowledge was about using `std::sort` and `std::array` and so on I would think that is more of a reason to use the standard library to its fullest extend, since that is where lots of people using c++ are sorely lacking

Answer (score 1):

`vector` is type `int[10]`.  Therefore, `vector* is type int(*)[10]`.  That is, a pointer to an array of 10 ints.  So the distance between `param[i]` and `param[i+1]` is `sizeof(int) * 10`

When you do this:

```
if (*param[i] > *param[i+1])
```

You are comparing one array of 10 ints to the next array of 10 ints.  I wish this would simply not compile, unfortunately, what happens is that the arrays are implicitly converted to pointers to their first element.  Since i < i+1, the above comparison will never be true.

Comment: Very wired i am a delphi coder so i am not really used to this... could you tell me a simple fix to my problem ?

Comment: @opc0de: Arrays have a lot of odd behavior left over from the C heritage.  That's why we have containers in the standard library, like `std::vector` and `std::array`.  Use those.